# Flip between two controls when a Boolean dependency property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have two user controls taking up the same space inside another control.

I have a Boolean dependency property called `ShowOtherGraph` that I change programmatically to toggle the visibility of these controls by using converters like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <generic:BooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
    <generic:InvertedBooleanVisibilityConverter x:Key="invertedVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And the controls are toggled like so:

```
<local:MyGraphControl x:Name="graph" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowOtherGraph, Converter={StaticResource invertedVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<local:MyOtherGraphControl x:Name="multiGraph" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowOtherGraph, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
```

What I would like to do is replace this with a horizontal flip effect (as if they are back to back and flipped horizontally) when the same Boolean dependency property changes.  Never used animations before for WPF.

Thank you...

Comment: It's not a comprehensive solution, so I'm commenting rather than answering, but I would suggest you start looking into data triggers and storyboards.

Comment: This has been asked before...

Comment: A link perhaps?  Couldn't find such a question, that's why I asked.